# my ejs page is not loading like other ejs page

Tags: node.js, ajax, ejs

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NU51g.png)   **this is my edit_admin code**

> Only in this page my html css is not getting load gretting an 404
>   error
>   i've tried alot but i can't get what's the actual reason behind this
>   kind of error
>   Refused to apply style from '' because its MIME type
>   ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type,andstrict MIME
>   checking is enabled in nodejs
>   Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:5000/admin/css/bootstrap3.3.7.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Admin</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap3.3.7.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font- 
       awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/dashboard.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- SIDE BAR START -->
      <%- include('../partials/admin_sidebar.ejs'); %>
    <!-- SIDE BAR END -->
    <section id="contents">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <!-- NAV BAR START -->
              <%- include('../partials/admin_navbar.ejs'); %>
        <!-- NAV BAR END -->
      </nav>
     <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row" style="background-color: white;">
         <div class="col-md-8">

        <form action="/admin/edit_admin/<%- admin.id %>" method="post">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" value="<%- admin.email %>" name="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="name@example.com">
          </div>
          <!-- <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">Example select</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
              <option>1</option>
              <option>2</option>
              <option>3</option>
              <option>4</option>
              <option>5</option>
            </select>
          </div> -->
          <div class="form-group">
             <label for="password">Password</label>
            <input type="password" value="<%- admin.password %>" name="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="password">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="submit">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='../js/main.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='../js/dashboard.js' type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your css file path for `http://localhost:5000/admin/css/bootstrap3.3.7.min.css` is incorrect.

Because it can not find the file on specified path, it goes to the 404 & returns html page of 404, which causes you to see this error

I would suggest to use absolute path for referring to your static css/js resource files as it might need to be accessed from various locations, relative path might not work if accessed from different places

To be sure that this is the error you have, just paste this url `http://localhost:5000/admin/css/bootstrap3.3.7.min.css` in your browser & see if you get css file there, if you see 404 page, the error is exactly what I explained above.

> UPDATE > Ideal way giving reference to assets in ejs

You can pass base_url like this in your routes while rendering ejs

```
res.render('edit', {
    base_url: "http://" + req.headers.host
})
```

And then specify link urls like this show it always catches the exact file no matter where you call it from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= base_url%>/css/bootstrap3.3.7.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= base_url%>/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/css/font- 
    awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= base_url%>/css/dashboard.css">
```

Comment: my other pages are working fine and the are on the same place as this file is!

Comment: Are all the page routes in the same level ? like it might work on pages with {url}/user but  might not work with {url}/admin/user since the second route is one level ahead so  relative reference to static files might not work same for this route

Comment: please share the code where you have specified routes, your main js file, and a snapshot of your folder structure, that would be helpful

Comment: i added a screenshot of the directory structure Please have a look

Comment: I am sure now that this route is one level ahead of other routes, try adding ../ one more time ahead of your bootstrap file src in code above, it would show correctly

Comment: yes that worked for me but why i have to specify my  path in this way only to this file and not in other files although my all the files are on same level

Comment: It's not about the file you specify but from the route where you link the file, so I would suggest that you use absolute path names for your css/js/images amongst all of your ejs files

Comment: I have updated my answer for you, this is how you can create absolute path for your assets & be sure its tracked right always

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify your assets folder in your nodejs app file.

```
app.use(“ASSETS_FOLDER”, express.static(“ASSETS_FOLDER”);
```

Comment: i did it like app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

Comment: So do you have all the files like css, js are on “public” folder ?

Comment: Try this app.use(“ public”, express.static(“ public”); instead of app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));

Comment: After adding app.use(“ public”, express.static(“ public”); remove "../" on your ejs pages
Like this: <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/bootstrap3.3.7.min.css">

Comment: if you admin_app.js is inside another folder in root directory of app, then try this app.use(“../public”, express.static(“ ../public”);